# Python Chapter 7 Lists and Tuples

Tags: python

Here is the question. Assume names references a list. Write a for loop that displays each element of the list. I don't know how to do this, can you please help me walk me through it? This is what I did. But this one is not right.

```
for element in the_list: 
print(element)
```

Comment: Hi Poone,

Are you getting an error or something? Perhaps you can tell us what you expect and what you're getting instead.

Comment: This is not very clear. Show a sample input and expected output, explain what is not working in your code right now.

Comment: I'm getting an error. This question asks to write a for loop that displays each element of the list.

Comment: @PooneKricanakarin Yeah, we got that part. What does the list look like! What is currently happening in the code you are showing that is leading you to believe it is not working?

Comment: Okay this is what I did on Python

Comment: list_name = ["Jenny", "Timmy", "Jackson", "Lucy"]                      
print(list_name)

Comment: OK. So why is the code you showed in your question not working?

Comment: Without seeing your error, but just guessing, you probably need to indent `print(element)'.

Comment: Okay how would I do that? @AbrahamB

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error that you're getting?

Comment: @PooneKricanakarin You are still really not clear. The example you gave looks very broken. You need to edit your question, but a real example with your real code and show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: for element in the_list: 
print(element) like this one @Abraham

Comment: That is the code, but what is the error message you receive if you run it? Or what is the output of the code vs what you're expecting?

Comment: For the error message it said name 'the_list' is not defined is talking about for element in the_list: @AbrahamB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define `the_list` first.

Try this code, for example:

```
the_list = ["Jenny", "Timmy", "Jackson", "Lucy"]
for element in the_list: 
  print(element)
```

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend a class like this one, by the way, if you're just getting started: https://www.udacity.com/course/programming-foundations-with-python--ud036

Answer (score 0):

> Assume names references a list

```
for name in names:
    print(name)
```